# Field Permissions History Query

Tags: soql, profile, permission-sets, workbench

I'm aware on how to run a query on FieldPermissions object to check the permissions for a specific field.

The question I have, and I haven't been able to find anything online yet, is:

If I run the query below:

```
SELECT Field,Id,ParentId,PermissionsEdit,PermissionsRead,SobjectType,SystemModstamp 
FROM FieldPermissions 
WHERE SobjectType = 'Case'
```

I get the following result (this is a small set of the result):

[image]

If a field isn't available for any Profile/Permission Set, the field will never show up in the query, for obvious reason.

Does anybody know if it's possible to query the history of a field's permission? Like if we removed access to a field to all profiles/permsets... What was the permission before the change was made?

Can't find anything online about it...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Only sort of, and likely not in the sense you're aiming at here.

You can query the [`SetupAuditTrail`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_setupaudittrail.htm#!) sObject, which is part of the [Setup Audit Trail](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/admin_monitorsetup.htm) feature. The audit trail tracks changes in your org for 180 days, so it's not a complete history of any specific field.

Additionally, the `SetupAuditTrail` object isn't structured to track at a fine level of granularity. If you change the FLS on a standard field for some custom profile `Custom Profile`, the corresponding `SetupAuditTrail` record shows

Section: Manage Users
Display: Changed profile Custom Profile: field-level security for Account: Account Number was changed from No Access to Read/Write
Action: profileFlsChangedCustom

Note that the change detail is available only in the field `Display`, which is a human-readable string that exclusively uses labels, rather than developer names.